# Formatting Cell values based on other cell values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am trying to format cell values based on text in another cells. I also process other data to create a dataframe called df3, which has columns called BCQA(F) and Status. I am writing df3 as a separate sheet in the same xlsx file I loaded.In that sheet I would like to change the background colour to red and write RED for row entries for Status if BCQA(F) equals NO DATES.

Any help would be great! This is what I am expecting the code to produce:

[image]

The code I have written is:

```
    wb=load_workbook('Swap status.xlsx')
    wb.create_sheet("ST_291123")
    ws=wb['ST_291123']
def swap_status(row):
  highlight1 = 'background-color: red;'
  highlight2 = 'background-color: green;'
  if row['BCQA (F)'] == 'NO DATES':
    return [highlight1]
  else:
    return [highlight2]

  df3.style.apply(swap_status, subset=['BCQA (F)'], axis=1)


for r in dataframe_to_rows(df3,index=False):
  ws.append(r)

wb.save('Swap status.xlsx')
```

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error ? Show FULL error message in question (not in comment) as text (not image). Do you get wrong result? Show it in question. We can't run your code, and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question.

Comment: maybe you should first get only column `'BCQA (F)'`  and compare with `'NO DATES'` to create list with `True, False` which you can use as `mask` with any other column. `mask = (df3['BCQA (F)'] == 'NO DATES')` and `df3["Status"][mask].style.apply( ...red... )` and `df3["Status"][mask] = "RED"`. And with inverted mask `~mask` set other color `df3["Status"][ ~mask].style.apply( ...green... )` and `df3["Status"][~mask] = "GREEN"`

Comment: it would be much simpler if you would create `minimal working code` with example data directly in code (as `DataFrame(...)`) so we could simply copy and test it - to create solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set value in new column then you can create `mask`

```
mask = (df['BCQA(F)'] == 'NO DATES')
```

and later use `mask` and inverted `~mask` to assign values

```
df['Status'] = ''  # create new column with empty strings
df['Status'][mask]  = 'RED'
df['Status'][~mask] = 'GREEN'
```

I expected that the same way it can change style - but it doesn't work.
`df['Status'][mask].style` crop dataframe to rows with `NO DATES`.
And `df.style.apply(... ,subset=mask)` raises error.

But you can use `mask` to create `iterator`

```
it = iter(mask)
```

and you use `next()` with this iterarator in function which sets style for other column(s)

```
mask = (df['BCQA(F)'] == 'NO DATES')

it = iter(mask)

def background(row):
    if next(it):   # get next value from `mask`
        return ['background-color: red;'] 
    else:
        return ['background-color: lime;']
    
dfs = df.style.apply(background, subset=['Status'], axis=1)
```

you can reduce it to

```
def background(row):
    return ['background-color: red;'] if next(it) else ['background-color: lime;']
    
dfs = df.style.apply(background, subset=['Status'], axis=1)
```

or even use as `lambda`

```
dfs = df.style.apply(
           lambda row:['background-color: red;'] if next(it) else ['background-color: lime;'],
           subset=['Status'], 
           axis=1
      )
```

BTW: if you plan to use iterator `it` in another functions then you have to create it again before every function: `it = next(mask)`

---

Later I found that `style.apply` can use `subset=(row_indexes, columns)` but it needs to convert `mask` (with boolean values) to list of indexes.

```
indexes_1 = df[mask].index
indexes_2 = df[~mask].index
```

and run two `apply` with different values

```
dfs = (df.style
       .apply(lambda row:['background-color: red;'],   subset=(indexes_1, 'Status'), axis=1)
       .apply(lambda row:['background-color: green;'], subset=(indexes_2, 'Status'), axis=1)
      )
```

---

Full working code which I used for tests:

(I use standard module `webbrowser` only to automatically see file `html` in web browser)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'BCQA(F)': ['NO DATES', 'NO DATES', '2021-06-08', '2021-06-08']
})

mask = (df['BCQA(F)'] == 'NO DATES')

df['Status'] = ''  # create column with empty strings
df['Status'][mask]  = 'RED'
df['Status'][~mask] = 'GREEN'

# -----

# version 1

it = iter(mask)

def background(row):
    if next(it):
        return ['background-color: red;'] 
    else:
        return ['background-color: lime;']
        
dfs = df.style.apply(background, subset=['Status'], axis=1)

# version 2

it = iter(mask)

def background(row):
    return ['background-color: red;'] if next(it) else ['background-color: lime;']
    
dfs = df.style.apply(background, subset=['Status'], axis=1)

# version 3

it = iter(mask)

dfs = df.style.apply(    
           lambda row:['background-color: red;'] if next(it) else ['background-color: lime;'],
           subset=['Status'], 
           axis=1
      )
           
# write as HTML
dfs.to_html('index_1.html')

# -----

indexes_1 = df[mask].index
indexes_2 = df[~mask].index

dfs = (df.style
       .apply(lambda row:['background-color: red;'],  subset=(indexes_1, 'Status'), axis=1)
       .apply(lambda row:['background-color: lime;'], subset=(indexes_2, 'Status'), axis=1)
      )

# write as HTML
dfs.to_html('index_2.html')

# -----

# open browser to display HTML or URL
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('index_1.html')
webbrowser.open('index_2.html')
```